# Validate short text answer against a list of words - Limesurvey

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate, limesurvey

I have designed a survey on Limesurvey (2.05+) where we ask respondents the name of the company where they work. I want an alert to pop up and prevent them from continuing if they enter words such as 'refused', 'declined', 'cannot divulge', etc. I hit up the guys over at Limesurvey forum and they gave me some code to try. The code works in Safari and IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox. The Limesurvey tech tested on his end and he said it worked on his Chrome. I cleared all cache, restarted browser, restarted the computer... tried outside of my work's VPN... had other people try it... to no avail.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 
  // Identify this question
  var thisQuestion = $('#question{QID}');
 
  // Define the disallowed strings and allert text
  var disallowed = ['refused', 'none of your business', 'nunya'];
  var alertText = 'You have entered an invalid string!';
 
  // Interrupt the Next/Submit click
  $('#movenextbtn, #movesubmitbtn').bind('click', function () {
   var thisInput = $('input.text', thisQuestion);
   var thisVal = thisInput.val();
   thisInput.removeClass('disallowed-string');
 
   // Loop through all disallowed strings
   $(disallowed).each(function() {
    // If disallowed string found in input value
    if(new RegExp('\\b'+this+'\\b', 'i').test(thisVal) == true) {
     thisInput.addClass('disallowed-string'); // Add a class
     alert(alertText); // Pop up alert
     return false; // Exit the loop
    }
   });
 
   // Abort the Next/Submit if we found a disallowed string
   if(thisInput.hasClass('disallowed-string')) {
    return false;
   }
  });
 
 });
```

What is it about this code that Firefox or Chrome does not like? I've had other code from a Lynda.com course that also does not work on Chrome, but works on Safari. Can we try the jquery-validate plug in? How could I adapt that to my situation?

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need access to the survey to check it out.

Thanks in advance.

J

Comment: Has anyone ever run into this?

Comment: any errors in chrome's console?

Comment: Hi. No errors in the chrome console.